# Large Number Entry in Oracle APEX

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Number field in DB and Oracle APEX.

My Issue is:

If Users want to entry the number data with this format "1.000.000,01", then takes Charakter Error that the entry must be Number.

How can I solve this problem in Application Layer ? In Database Layer there are some solutions , but in Application Layer so far I can not find any solution.

As Summary: I want to entry number as 1.000.000,12 in Application and I want to see it in the same format.

NOT: A procedure runs in the Application to insert the data in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can/should set appropriate format mask, e.g. `999G999G990D00` where

- `G` represents *thousands* character (dot in your case)
- `D` represents *decimal* character (comma in your case)

But, where do you set NLS numeric characters (represented by `G` and `D`)? In Apex 20.2, it is to be set in:

- application builder
- shared components
- globalization attributes
- security
- initialization PL/SQL code - in here, you'll probably see what they are set to. Change those values, if necessary. For example:

  ```
  begin
    execute immediate q'[alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.']';
    execute immediate q'[alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss']';
  end;
  ```

Comment: First of all thank you for your support. I have set the format mask, and I see now the values as 2.000,10. It is Ok for me. But when the user want to enter the data in the same format (as 2.000,10), take "X Field must be numeric value" error. It is my issue. I would like to moderate my application according to this type of data entry. In Addition to thisI have just made your update in security Initilization PL/SQL Code, unfortunately it didn`t work.

Comment: And I live this issue only when I use packages/procedures. I assign this field/value/variable as Number. When I don't use packages , there isn't any  problem.